# Mockito - Mock autowired repository in service

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I'm triying to write a test from a controller.
The controller call a service who call an autowired repository.

Here is my class right now

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AdminDestinationControllerTest {

private final PTUser user = new PTUser();
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@InjectMocks
private AdminDestinationController adminDestinationController;

@Mock private RoutingDestinationServiceImpl  routingDestinationService;
@Mock private PTRoutingDestinationRepository destinationRepository;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(adminDestinationController).build();
}

@Test
public void setCost_UnknownCode() throws Exception {
    when(routingDestinationService.setCost(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();
    when(destinationRepository.setCost(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
    mockMvc.perform(post("/admin/destinations/cost").content("{\"code\":\"99999\", \"cost\":\"2\"}").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}
}
```

But in the service, the repository is null.
Any ideas of how I could do ?

Thank you

Comment: Well, the service is a `Mock` as well, there is no injection happening in Mocks. You have to mock the methods in the `RoutingDestinationServiceImpl` which are being called from the `AdminDestinationController`.

Comment: Just don't call the real method of the mocked service. And write a unit test for the service.